# Smoothing out two concrete floor levels for laminate

Tags: flooring, floor, laminate-floor

I had an old external wall removed from between the original house and an extension built by the previous owners.

Then I had someone install a laminate floor across the area, he assured me he’d reduce the step between the heights by feathering. Problem is he did a bad job of it, the feathering is across too short an area and isn’t even feathered in some area.

Any suggestions on the best thing to use for feathering in at all? Is standard floor leveler too runny or can I build it up carefully in layers? What do you think an appropriate area to loose the slope over is? The difference in heights is around 13mm. Unfortunately the rest of the area is too large and not feasible for me to raise by 13mm right now.

Or do I just cut my losses and run two different height floors with a transition bar in the middle of the room? The width of the area is 3.7m.

Thanks for any suggestions.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used quick drying non cementitious leveler such as this: [Savogran Floor Leveler](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000BO8NWW) before in a similar situation.
It worked well.

For your area you will have to feather about a meter out from the high edge, possibly further.  This product dries fast. you will need probably 4 bags. Mix only about 1/2 bag at a time at first. Mixing water a little at at time until it is about the consistency of pancake batter. ( it will thicken quickly).

Pour it along the high edge and trowel it out. Longer trowels are preferred. You can mix more and pour as you get used to working with it.  Feather it out and don't panic if there are some high and low spots. The product can be sanded and dips can be filled. If it is too uneven and needs to be smoother, you can mix it thinner and pour it over the feathering and allow it to run into low areas. That would be worse case scenario, as working in layers should get you a good result.

Comment: Thanks so much @RMDman